# Watson Assistant - Spel | How to check whether values exist at a certain array index?

Tags: arrays, spring-el

I would like to check whether certain values are contained at a certain index in the array.

With the following statement I can check whether "Value1" is contained at position "1":
'''$myArray.get(1).contains('value1')'''

What if I want to check at position "1" whether "Value1" or "Value2" are included (or more than two).

I would like to avoid creating multiple conditions with OR links in the Watson Assistant Node.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to create multiple conditions you can use regex.

```
String[] myArray = {"Value1", "Value2", "Value3"};
myArray[1].matches("(Value1|Value2|Value3)");  <-- will return true
```

You can basically add as much values as you want as a parameter to the `matches()` function.

So in the end your SpEL expression should look something like this:

```
"#myArray[1].matches('(Value1|Value2|Value3)')"
```

Comment: In Watson Assistant it will be something like: `<? input.text.matches("v1|v2|v3") ?>`